# Regex: Extract string with words surrounded by curly braces, if it contains a text

Tags: python, regex

**Input**

I've a string like this:

```
string_ = "abc {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} } \n abc { lmn {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }"
```

I need to extract the values in curly braces, if it contains the string 'def', using python regex.

**Output**

Expected output:

```
 "{def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno} } }"
```

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: can you please post what's your expected output?

Comment: How have you tried to  solve your problem? What was exactly the problem that is blocking you?

Comment: please show what you have tried, if you are asking for a solution without trying yourself firt it's offtopic

Comment: Please tell me the pyhton re - which could extract {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno} } } from the input. When I tired I am getting an output {def {ghi} .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'({def(?:.*)[{].*[}])')
string_ = "abc {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} } \n abc { lmn {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }"

result = pattern.search(string_)
print(result.group(1))
```

Comment: This fails when input string is "abc {mno} {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} } \n abc { lmn {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }". I need the {values in braces} if it has def.

Comment: I missed the 'def' part of the question. Fixed!

Comment: This regex will go till the last '}' in the string. It doesn't manage the open-closed pairs of curly braces.

Comment: Yes This is perfect. Thanks. Just One more doubt, If I remove  the \n from the string like-  string_ = "abc {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }  abc { lmn {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }", What should be the regex?

Comment: What the output should be in this case?

Comment: Input string_ = "abc {mno} {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} } abc { lmn {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} } Output = {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
string_ = "abc {def {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }  abc { lmn {ghi} { {jkl} {mno}} }"
result = re.search(r'{\s*def(\s*{.*?}\s*)*}(\s*})*',string_)
print(result.group())
```

This simple yet a bit lengthy regex works **with or without '\n' delimiter**.

The way it works is:

`{\s*def` : this searches a curly brace to start with and then searches for def with 0+ whitespace in between.

`(\s*{.*?}\s*)*}` : this searches for multiple instance of {...} pair, however two problems arrise here first, we need to disable greedy with `?` else it will go till the end of the string. Second, it can't keep a track of proper bracket pairs, (that's a job of recurssion), so for it `{ {abc}` is a valid bracket pair. How to fix this ?

`(\s*})*` : This fixes that. It captures all the rest left closing braces. (here I have done an assumption but until it doesn't do a problem in your case I won't mention it)

Look I assume a pattern in your type of string you gave. And if this doesn't work for any string let me know.